# Conic bundle: find the locus of the centers

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry

Consider the conic bundle: $\mathcal{C_{\lambda,\mu}} : \lambda(4x_0^2+3x_1^2-4x_ox_2-2x_1x_2)+\mu(4x_0^2+5x_1^2+4x_0x_1-8x_0x_2-4x_1x_2)=0$

*Find the locus of the centers of those conics and write the equation.*

How to find it? I did this, but I think I was following the wrong way:

The matrix which represents the bundle is:

$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    4\lambda+4\mu & 2\mu & -2\lambda-4\mu \\
    2\mu & 3\lambda+5\mu & -\lambda-2\mu \\
    -2\lambda-4\mu & -\lambda-2\mu & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

from the theory I know that I can find the center of a conic solving this system:

$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    c_{11} & c_{12} \\
    c_{12} & c_{22} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ = $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -c_{01} \\
    -c_{02} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ replacing: $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    3\lambda+5\mu & -\lambda-2\mu \\
    -\lambda-2\mu & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ = $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -2\mu \\
    2\lambda+4\mu \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

then $ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  3\lambda+5\mu&-\lambda-2\mu&-2\mu\\
  -\lambda-2\mu&0&2\lambda+4\mu
\end{array}
\right] $ , after passages: $ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1&0&-2\\
  0&1&-2(\lambda+3\mu)
\end{array}
\right] $.

So the coordinates of the center should be $[1, -2, -2(\lambda+3\mu)]$. Is this right? There are other ways? Thank you

Comment: In an affine where $(x_0:x_1:x_2)=(x:y:1)$ i.e. $\lambda(4x^2+5y^2+4yx-8x-4y)+\mu (4x^2+3y^2-4x-2y)$ you can differentiate wrt $x$ and $y$ and solve the resulting system to get: $(x,y) = (\frac{3\mu+4\lambda}{6\mu+4\lambda}, \frac{\mu}{3\mu+2\lambda})$.

Comment: The center is the pole (as in pole-polar relation) to the line at infinity. How is your line at infinity represented? Suppose it is $[1:0:0]$, then just multiply that with the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), i.e. pick the first column of the cofactor matrix.

Comment: Related keyword: [Nine-point conic](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1967142).

Comment: You can do a simple sanity check of your solution: for $\lambda=1$, $\mu=0$, does it produce the center of the first conic? Does $\lambda=0$, $\mu=1$ produce the center of the second?

Comment: @amd the easiest the better, thank you! And thank to everyone.